# Distinct based on first and last characters on the items in list C#

Tags: c#, list, select, distinct

I have a list of strings:

```
"55002",
"81512",
"81612",
"84515",
"84615",
"86358",
"86358",
"91128",
"94002"
```

I want to find in that list items that have the same 2 first characters and the same last characters and then remove from list the one which has lower middle character. In this example  the same would be: `81512` and `81612` and I want to remove `81512`, the same would be `84515` and `84615` and I want to remove `84515` etc.

Comment: Lowest middle character - which entries are compared? All? Adjacent?

Comment: So the return result would be `"55002", "81612", "84615", "86358", "91128", "94002"`?

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: How will be the middle characters compared? Are they all integers? Or they will be sorted by character ASCII value?

Comment: @Ivan86 So ????

Comment: @Ivan86 And homework resolved by Royi Namir , just please give the best grade from your master !!!

Comment: @RoyiNamir I addressed to Ivan86 comment and did't want to say why you answered, by the way I was trying to answer it but you were fast, when I put !!! at the end of my sentences means I am not serious, any way I agree with you.

Comment: @Aria Oh Sorry For not catching that :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'm surprised that you don't share the same viewpoint as I do since you're a long time SO user.. I've been downvoted many times doing the same as you just did, and wondered why until I got an explanation. 1.) He did not show any effort to solve the problem himself. 2.) When he gets his next assignment he'll be back. 3.) By supporting this people get encouraged to upload homework to SO. 4.) He is not getting any smarter by you serving him the complete asnwer to his `homework`. So I don't understand what you are supporting here.

Comment: @Aria I'm sorry, I don't understand this: _just please give the best grade from your master_. But FYI I will not downvote the question because it is clear and understandable. I will also not downvote the answer because it is also clear and understanbale. But I will not upvote them either. I have been taught, here on SO, by some high reputation users (>100k) not to support homework. I agree with them.

Comment: @Ivan86, Sorry it was misunderstanding about give and get !!!, but I think so, the question and the answer are clear both, it is easy to know asked question is homework or not , anyway I would like answer them also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
var g = new string[] {"55002",  ...};

var t=g.GroupBy(f => f.Substring(0, 2))
       .Select(f =>f.OrderByDescending(a =>a ).First());
```

Result :

```
55002 
91128 
81612 
84615 
86358 
94002
```

update :

I probably missed that groupby should be also mathing the last two charcters .

If that's the case then :

```
var t=g.GroupBy(f => f.Substring(0, 2)+f.Substring( f.Length-2))
       .Select(f =>f.OrderByDescending(a =>a ).First());
```

For visualization :

Looking at this code :

```
    var g = new string[] {"55002",
"91128",
"81512",
"81712",
"81612",
"84516",
"84216",
"84615",
"86358",
"86358",
"94002"};

    var t = g.GroupBy(f => f.Substring(0, 2) + f.Substring(f.Length - 2)).Select(f => new { key = f.Key, group = f.OrderByDescending(a => a)});
    Console.Write(t);
```

We're going to group by the "key" and to take the first top one in each right group :

[image]

Comment: This does not even solve the problem. Try with the following input: {"81512",
"81612", "81613"}. This returns only 81613. 81612 should also be on the list based on the requirement.

Comment: @yildizm85 Not according to my understanding.

Comment: @yildizm85 Accodring to his demo he groups by 2 chars and then delete the ones with the REST of charcters where when sorted - it takes the biggest value.

Comment: "same last characters"

Comment: @yildizm85 Edited.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Are you sure `Console.Write(t);` write the numbers ? I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var input = new []{ "1234", "2345" /*...*/};
var res = input.GroupBy(x=> x.Substring(0,2)).Select(x=> x.OrderByDescending(y=>y).ToList()).ToList();
foreach(var l in res)
{
    l.RemoveAt(l.Count-1);
}
```

This will remove last string in literal order, but it will cover your case